# How can I alter the properties of a class to match some imported properties via a JSON file, retaining the types of the original class?

Tags: json, typescript, class

I'm very new to programming; sorry if this has already been answered - I couldn't find an appropriate solution!

```
export class creature {
    pos: vector2;
    target: vector2;
    path: Array<vector2>;
    length: number;
    maxDist: number;
    weights: number;
    id: string;
    mainArrayId: number;
    segments: Array<creatureJoint>;
    head: creatureHead;
    legs: Array<creatureJoint>;
    interactingId: string;
    state: string;
    traits: { [key: string] : number };
    health: number;
    energy: number;
```

I have a creature class with some property types defined as classes elsewhere. My save/load system involves stringify()ing this object, then to load, parse()ing that and creating a new instance of a creature class, then populating that creature class with the properties extracted from the parsed JSON file.

```
export function replaceCurrentState(loadedState : { [key : string]: creature }) : void {
    creatures = [];
    deadCreatures = [];
    creaturesReference = {};

    Object.keys(loadedState).forEach(function(i) {
        new creature(new vector2(0,0),16,4,2,i);
        let baseCreature : creature = creaturesReference[i];
        let loadCreature : creature = loadedState[i];
        for (let [key, value] of Object.keys(baseCreature)) {
        }
    });
}
```

The issue is that the JSON file cannot consider the original class/type and loads them as generic objects instead of, for example, vector2() classes.

So far I've tried hard-coding the properties in and several different scripts that all just iterate through the properties and just set the new creature's property to the loaded creature's property, but it keeps giving me "cannot assign to type never" errors.

Comment: `classes` have no built in way to serialize data, you will need to handle this yourself, eg. having some methods called `load` / `save`,  you could then serialize to a JSON object and deserialize from a JSON object, but assigned to your object needs to be handled manuallly.

Comment: Generally you will need `cls.toJSON(): Pick<Cls, 'saved'|'keys'>` and `static Cls.fromJSON(data: Pick<Cls, 'saved'|'keys'>){return Object.assign(new Cls(), data)}`